# CakePHP 3.2: how to handle exceptions in shell

Tags: cakephp

Suppose I have an utility class in my CakePHP APP. Simple, this utility allows me to perform some tasks.
The utility may generate some exceptions, like any other class.

Now I am creating a shell and this shell also use this utility.
Then using the shell, exceptions can be generated.
In my terminal, these exceptions are shown along with the application layout.

So my question is: how can I properly handle these exceptions?
In the shell I should implement some constructs that occur earlier and avoid that by using this utility may throw exceptions?

Practical example:
My utility allows you to create database backups. I want it to be an utility because it can be used in multiple contexts, for example also in a controller (in the application's admin panel, you can execute a database backup).
Among many other things, the utility checks if the directory where you are creating the backup is writable, and if it is not throw an exception.
Now, if I use the utility in a shell and if I'm trying to create a backup into a non-writable directory, this exception is thrown.

Is it correct? Maybe in the shell I should check that the directory is writable, before using the utility, and then I should use the `Cake\Console\Shell::abort()` method? In this way, however, I will have to implement the same code twice.

Thanks.

---

EDIT

Some ***stupid*** code example, just to make you understand what I'm talking about.

```
class MyUtility {
    public function create($filename, $data) {
        if(!is_writable(dirname($filename)))
            throw new InternalErrorException(__('File or directory `{0}` not writeable', dirname($filename)));

        return file_put_contents($filename, $data);
    }
}

class MyStupidShell extends Shell {
    public function main() {
        if($this->param('filename') && $this->param('data')) {
            $this->out(__('Ok, I will create the file {0}', $this->param('filename')));
            MyUtility::create($this->param('filename'), $this->param('data'));
        }
    }
}

$ bin/cake MyStupid --filename /not/writable/directory/myfile.txt --data "hello world"
```

Comment: I don't really get your actual problem... your shell task dies hard on an unhandled exception, and you want to avoid that? `try ... catch` then?

Comment: @ndm I do not have any problem. I'm sorry, maybe I explained badly. I wanted to know if it is correct to organize the code so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @ndm:

```
class MyUtility {
    public function create($filename, $data) {
        if(!is_writable(dirname($filename)))
            throw new InternalErrorException(__('File or directory `{0}` not writeable', dirname($filename)));

        return file_put_contents($filename, $data);
    }
}

class MyStupidShell extends Shell {
    public function main() {
        if($this->param('filename') && $this->param('data')) {
            try {
                $this->out(__('Ok, I will create the file {0}', $this->param('filename')));
                MyUtility::create($this->param('filename'), $this->param('data'));
            }
            catch(InternalErrorException $e) {
                $this->abort($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

$ bin/cake MyStupid --filename /not/writable/directory/myfile.txt --data "hello world"
```

Comment: @ndm, is this the best way?

Comment: I wouldn't use the term "best", but that's for sure a totally reasonable way way to handle possible exceptions if you want things to fail gracefully.